# Amazon s3 java sdk, SSL Handshake exception encountered when openStream() is called on a presigned URL

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using a service that returns the a pre signed url for an object. When I try to open the content using `url.openStream()` I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xxx.s3.amazonaws.com found.`
I need to return an input stream and I am pretty much cramped with the specs. I read through other questions but I did not find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason. It was because my bucketName had a '.' in it. So a certificate issued by s3.amazonaws.com is valid for the subdomain mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com. So if you have something like mybucket.mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com then it is not considered as a sub domain of s3.amazonaws.com and hence there occurs a certificate mismatch.

Comment: But a strange thing is, that this occurs not regularly - although we use always the same bucket name with a '.' in it. Often this happens in the middle during the second connection (after one before - not at the same time)...

Comment: Having a similiar issue... though it does not occur regularly My bucketid has "-" and objectid has "."  Can the issue be persistent cz of that?